# Algorithm to find prime numbers

Tags: prime-numbers

For a loop up to positive integer $n$, I have deduced an algorithm that provides me with all the prime numbers plus some odd numbers, for example for $n=10000$ my algorithm gives me the count $1260$ while prime are $1229$.

In order to avoid the non-primes I run a loop till $1260$ and remove the numbers that are divisible by any of the number from the list of $1260$ numbers (provide from my algorithm) which provides me the exact number of primes ?

Is my approach correct or do I need to reconsider something?

Comment: How would we know whether the algorithm is correct or not if you haven't told us what it is. For instance, there is no way for us to know whether you missed a prime somewhere.

Comment: Ever heard of the Sieve of Eratosthenes? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Comment: Show us the alien numbers.

Comment: if your algorithm gave you non-prime numbers, then it has a glitch in it.  The simplest algorithm I can think of is to count numbers from 2 to n-1 that are factors n, and if the count is zero, then n is prime.  Are your 'failures' squares of odd primes, by any chance?  On a computer it may be due to rounding errors, especially if you are using square root and floats

Comment: At the very least tell us what some of these false primes you are getting are, these "pseudoprimes" if you will. Numbers like 91 and 4199?

Comment: For n=1000, these are the non primes 6,15,65,133,435,529,561,793

Comment: For n=1000, these are the non primes 6,15,65,133,435,529,561,793